# How do I provide feedback to Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator

Is asking a question on Stack Overflow the only way to provide developer feedback to Appcelerator and Appcelerator Labs? That is, not reporting a bug or requesting a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly use Stack Overflow. Myself and several others from Appcelerator support, dev relations, and engineering teams do monitor Stack Overflow daily.

If you are looking for a less public way to drop us a message, you can log into [platform.appcelerator.com](https://platform.appcelerator.com/) and click the Intercom icon in the lower right to talk directly with someone from Appc, though I think it's mostly support and sales on the other end.

Twitter is another good way to get ahold of us: [@appcelerator](https://twitter.com/appcelerator). It's monitored by a number of folks across departments.

Lastly, you can contact me directly via Twitter at [@cb1kenobi](https://twitter.com/cb1kenobi) or email me at cbarber(at)appcelerator(dot).com. I'm one of the most senior level engineers and have touched almost every product at some point. If I can't help you, I know who can. :)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is a great place, but not for all types of support.

You can read some of their thoughts on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Let's go through the different types of questions/feedback they mention:

- How do I? -- Stack Overflow tag [appcelerator](/questions/tagged/appcelerator)
- I got this error, why? -- Stack Overflow tag [appcelerator](/questions/tagged/appcelerator)
- I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug -- [Appcelerator JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org/)
- I have an idea/request -- [Appcelerator JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org/)

OK, that was simple, but now the last two:

- Why do you?
- When will you?

Right now we don't have a clear path for these. We are working on improving guidance on this, including from the Appcelerator Labs pages.

The best place Chris mentioned is Intercom which can be reached via the **?** icon on the bottom right of https://platform.appcelerator.com and other properties. You can also send an email to support@appcelerator.com. Like Miga says another good place is TiSlack since a lot of Appcelerator staff hangs out there s well.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback is a fairly generic term, if you are looking for a place to report a bug or to request a future enhancement, I would recommend creating a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?filter=17279).

Comment: another communication way is to use ti-slack (http://tislack.org/). There are some appc-devs too.

Comment: I guess I used "feedback" because that’s what the Appcelerator Labs page requests — “We appreciate any feedback you may have on these products” — and a description of my experience with one some of the pre-release software is what I was wanting to provide. That is: neither a bug nor a question nor a feature request.

Comment: join us on tislack, there is a #hyperloop section or the #general channel for all things ti! And on jira is a community section (AC); issues can be bug, new feature, improvement or story. So if its something that could improve a product you can file an issue, too

Answer (score 0):

I had not noticed it before, but in the bottom right corner of Appcelerator Studio is a speech-bubble icon. When you click on it, it calls up a Feedback Form that asks "How can we improve? Tell us what you like and what can be better."

Questions I can direct here to Stack Overflow, bugs and feature requests to [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org), confusions to tislack or twitter — and this is where I can provide comments and just general feedback.

So, along with all the other avenues pointed out by Chris, Mark, miga and Fokke, this answers my question.